# How to pass data from page to another page

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys i have a react project made with react, node, express, and mysql. The thing is i want to get email from login and pass to home page. How do i do that, i dont want to use useParams() because the user can input their email in the link, i want to avoid that. Is there any way to do that and if you can, can you give code example.

**Login**

```
const Login = () => {

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const [emailLog, setEmailLog] = useState("");
  const [passwordLog, setPasswordLog] = useState("");

  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login" , {
      email: emailLog, 
      password: passwordLog
    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response)

      if(response.data.message) {
        alert((response.data.message))
      } else{
        setLoginStatus(response.data[0].email)
        alert("Redirecting")
        navigate("/home")
      } 
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login').then((response)=> {
      if(response.data.loggedIn == true) {
        setLoginStatus(response.data.email[0].email)
      }
    })
  })
 
  return (
    <div>
    <img className="wave" src={Wave} />
    <img className="wave2" src={WaveV2} />
    <div className="wrapper">
      
        <div className="img">
            {/* <img src={Background}/> */}
        </div>

        <div className="register-content">
        <div className='registerForm'>
                <img src={Avatar} />
                <h2 className="title">Welcome</h2>
                <div className="input-div one">
                   <div className="i">
                        <i className="fas fa-user"><GrMail /></i>
                   </div>
                   <div className="div">
                        <input type="email" className="input" placeholder='Email' required 
                    onChange={(e)=> {
                      setEmailLog(e.target.value)
                    }}/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="input-div pass">
                   <div className="i"> 
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"><AiFillLock /></i>
                   </div>
                   <div className="div">
                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder='Password' required
                    onChange={(e)=> {
                      setPasswordLog(e.target.value)
                    }}/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <a href="/">Don't have an account ?</a>
              <button  type='submit' className='btn' onClick={login} data={emailLog}>Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  )
}

export default Login
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [invoice, setInvoice] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState ("");
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState ("IDR");
 

  const [ myFile, setMyFile] = useState("");
  const [test, setTest] = useState("anjay@anjay.com");


  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <BasicExample />
    <div className='formInput'>
      <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/upload'>
     <div className='textUser'>
      <h1>{props.data}</h1>
     </div>
          
          <input className='inputForm' defaultValue={test} type="email" disabled  name='email'  />
          

          <input className='inputForm'  type="number" placeholder='Invoice No' name='InvoiceNo'  />

        
          <input className='inputForm'  type="date" name='Invoice_Date'  />

          <input className='inputForm'  type="text" placeholder='Description' name='Description'  />
        
          <select className='selectBox' name='Currency' onChange={(e)=> {
            setCurrency(e.target.value);
          }}>
            <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="YEN">YEN</option>
          </select>

         
           <input className='inputForm'  type="number" placeholder='Amount' name='Amount'/>

          <input  className='custom-file-upload' multiple  type="file" name="DocumentFile" onChange={(e)=> {
            setMyFile(e.target.value);
          }} />
          
         

          <button className='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Suggestion is, whenever creating application try to use redux to store data in centralized manner. And if don't want to use redux, you can store email in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think props drilling should solve it.
example

**Login Component**

```
function Login({email, setEmail}){
  // you need to update state email here
}
```

**Home or App.js**

```
function App(){
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  // here you should pass the props to login component,
  // so you have the ability to set or asign the email state
  <Login email={email} setEmail={setEmail} />
}
```

Comment: i cant do that, coz i dont want to call the login function in app.js. I just wanna display the email(from login) in default value form.

Comment: that seems you need a state management to store data globally, so you can use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data tp one page, you can use state with navigate.

```
navigate("/home", {state: { email: emailLog }})
```

you can get data from your home component like,

```
{props.location.state.email}
```

Comment: can it be used if the email stored in state ?